# Pandas_Excel Changing Format and dtype

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe comes that comes from sql.

[image]

Date columns are not the ones that I can process. So I need to change the format like "%d.%m.%t %H:%m".when I try to change the format with:

```
df3["ACT_START_DATE"]=pd.to_datetime(df3["ACT_START_DATE"])
df3["ACT_START_DATE"]=df3["ACT_START_DATE"].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%m")
```

Result

[image]

1- why do the HOUR changes ?

2- Beside hour changing, is there another way to do for all date columns at once ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the date appear in Excel as a string, or a Date type?

Comment: in excel, it appears as "General"

Answer (score 1):

The "minute" part is changing because your format is wrong

Notice the format: `%d.%m.%Y %H:%m` 
`%m` is actually for MONTH 
So instead of exporting for minute, you're exporting the month value there.

Change it to `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S` and you'll be fine 
(Notice the difference is capital M vs small m)

As for changing multiple columns, you can simply use

```
my_df[['column1','column2']] =     
my_df[['column1','column2']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M%S')
```

or something along those lines as you prefer

Comment: first, thank you for responding. but gives 
ValueError: ("time data '2019-12-29 08:00:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M' (match)", 'occurred at index ACT_START_DATE')

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You see the data is "2019-12-29 08:00:00" and the format is "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" so clearly it's missing the "seconds" parameter. So just change the format to include seconds like this: `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S`. I've updated the answer

Comment: still gives error. it wants me at write the format as source "%Y-%m-%d...." Then i use dt.strftime(format) but apply method doesnt work. Another problem if value is blank or null, it returns "NaT".